# Error when I try to run Tomcat 7

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have a simple J2ee application with Spring mvc.
So when I try to run the server Tomcat 7.0 I have this error, but the application works.

```
The error is:

Grave: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Users\michele.castriotta\Dropbox\workspace_j2ee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringMVC does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

feb 18, 2015 9:31:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Error in resourceStart()
feb 18, 2015 9:31:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Error getConfigured
feb 18, 2015 9:31:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Context [/SpringMVC] startup failed due to previous errors
feb 18, 2015 9:31:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
feb 18, 2015 9:31:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
feb 18, 2015 9:31:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Informazioni: Server startup in 4181 ms
```

What file I can posted?? For find this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [SEVERE: Error starting static Resources in Tomcat server console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603759/severe-error-starting-static-resources-in-tomcat-server-console)

Comment: Try This,Answer

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12217111/1878022

I think it will help you

Comment: I have see this link, but I don't have fixed my error, but I have see that the error is on this path:
"tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringMVC"
this path, not exist and it is right, because my application name is spring_mvc

Comment: I have find this folder:
C:\Users\michele.castriotta\Dropbox\workspace_j2ee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost
but in the localhost folder there isn't a xml file. This folder is empty

Comment: I have fixed the error, editing the file server.xml into eclipse under server folder. Now I don't have this problem.